# How to hide the auto generated border of <select> dropdown menu with CSS?

Tags: css

I have fully hidden my select options `display: none;` as I am using a Customized element as an other select. For multiple reason I need it to work this way.

The issue is the following dropdown **rounded border/bubble** is still showing when I click the select element. I have tried on multiple browsers and the same appears:

[image: select option white black bg]

[image: select option border black bg]

*(Don't mind the white background with "Whisky" word, that's actually my 2nd element that acts as a fully customized select.)*

When I click anywhere, even on the Console source it disappears.

**Is there any way to make this completely disappear with CSS**?
Or do I need to re-create an element that's not a `<select>` tag?

So far I have tried these and not working:

```
#product-select option{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position:absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Might be a duplicate question of [Select menu option border none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none) that is looking to remove the border of the select element. If yes please close.

PS: been a while since posted here as an OP, don't grill me ;)

Cheers

Comment: If you are replacing the whole thing with a custom element - then why are you only hiding the options, and not the select element itself?

Comment: Show your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

Sadly we can not do that.

### Demo

Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599070/8274308). It's an old answer of mine. It shows some of the things we are able to customize. But that border is not customizable by CSS. We have no access to it.

Comment: Thanks for that.. Yeah unfortunately it seems to be a limitation !

Answer (score 0):

try outline:unset; usually it is not border but its outline.

Comment: Not working, thanks anyway :)